# Почему косАрь, а не кОсарь?

Tags: фонетика

В связи с ответом на вопрос об этимологии слова **знахарь** меня заинтересовало следующее.
 В словах пАхарь, жИхарь, знАхарь удврение падает на первый слог. Почему в образованном по той же парадигме слове косАрь ударение на втором слоге?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нет какого-то правила, даже статистического.
Помимо названных вами, есть ложкАрь, скобАрь и т.п. и еще масса слов с двойной возможностью (рЫбарь-рыбАрь).
Возможно, что к ударению на древнем суфиксе тяготеют слова образованные непосредственно от предмета, а не от глагола. Но и это только предположение.